# JWT seems to be not secure solution for a REST API

Tags: api, rest, authentication, jwt, authorization

I am developing a REST API but JWT's looks wrong to me. We all calling them as "stateless tokens" but actually they brings a lot of problems.

We all say, they should not be stored in a database or memory cache solutions. But there are 3 core conditions about that API for me, please enlighten me about how can I implemented them without accessing / store them in DB.

1. When user changes his password, the token should be invalidated
   immediately.
2. When user log-out, the token should be invalidated
   immediately.
3. The architecture should be available to scale horizontally easily. I don't want a trouble.

If we do database/cache lookups in each request for those conditions, JWT is a totally useless solution, Isn't it?

Comment: Is there any new comments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JWTs allow for forced expiration like you are looking for. What you are looking to use is more of a reference token which can be found here https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html?highlight=reference.

With that being said, JWTs still are still very useful. They are best implemented with very short expiration dates however.

Comment: I am seeing lots of API's using JWTs in the wrong way. Because, the conditions I mentioned in the above are really common stuffs for a REST API.

If you set the very short expiration dates, that still does not provide a right thing. One minute is one minute. It should be invalidated, This is a security weakness.

Comment: You might find some of the answers for how to "expire" a JWT token here https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/. however, that is not logic that is built into the JWT framework, that is something that you have to build on top of it. JWT tokens are very useful but they do have some trade offs that must have their risks accepted.

Comment: If I use a Redis whitelist for those JWT tokens. What would be? Is it something hard to scale?

Comment: I'm unsure. We use reference tokens when we need the strict ability to expire any token. I have not used Redis caching before.

Comment: Is this reference token something stored in database directly?

Comment: Not outside the Identity server. We pass around the reference key similar to a jwt but make calls back to the identity server to validate.

Comment: the drawback is heavier network traffic due to the extra calls but we have places where it is necessary.